# A circular image view is being rectangle when make it hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c

I make a circular imageView. Here is the code:

```
someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-35,80,80,80)];

[someImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
someImageView.layer.cornerRadius = someImageView.frame.size.height /2;
someImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
someImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
someImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:16.0f/255.0f
                                                  green:56.0f/255.0f
                                                   blue:70.0f/255.0f
                                                  alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
someImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
[self.view addSubview:someImageView];
```

But when I make it hidden, I notice a rect(original size) for a very little time and then hidden. Why this happen? I want to make it  circular when I will hidden yes or no.

Comment: is this is the view did load or the vieewDid appear?

Comment: I create this imageView in ViewWillAppear.

Comment: can you try to create it in didload and check?

Comment: It happens same when I create it in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear.

Comment: Try to use clipsToBounds = true  instead of maskToBounds. It is a UIView parameter, not layer one. So it will be someImageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: just change the alpha then hide it

Comment: Woof , I have tried as you say but nothing happened. Tj3n , which alpha I will change? Actually someImageView is a rectangle shape view, so when set an image it set in the rectangle shape. Then I make this circular. But when I hidden this, it back to its actual shape and hidden.

Comment: `someImageView` will have alpha value, also try change `someImageView` background color to alpha = 0 color

Comment: just put this before you add it to the subview someImageView.alpha = 0;

Comment: As Tj3n's advice I change the background color to alpha=0, but it remains same problem and as Mohammad Bashir Sidani's advice I add this "someImageView.alpha = 0" before add it to the subview, but as a result someImageView is disappear from the initial .

Comment: And what if you will set a background for that imageView same as a controller view, or make it clear colored?

Comment: Woof, my image view background color is clear color, same as controller view.